# Shortcode with woocommerce_before_customer_login_form won't reference overridden template file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am currently using wordpress and am creating a customized theme, i succesfully over-ridden the old myaccount form-login.php file as it works perfectly for the my-account page, but I used a shortcode from [here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-separate-login-registration/) and used it on my theme

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_reg_form_bbloomer', 'bbloomer_separate_registration_form' );
 
function bbloomer_separate_registration_form() {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return '<p>You are already registered</p>';
   ob_start();
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
   $html = wc_get_template_html( '/myaccount/form-login.php' );
   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
   $dom->loadHTML( utf8_decode( $html ) );
   $xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
   $form = $xpath->query( '//form[contains(@class,"register")]' );
   $form = $form->item( 0 );
   echo $dom->saveXML( $form );
   return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'wc_login_form_bbloomer', 'bbloomer_separate_login_form' );

function bbloomer_separate_login_form() {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return '<p>You are already logged in</p>'; 
   ob_start();
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
   woocommerce_login_form( array( 'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) );
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

So after putting calling the shortcode in 2 separate pages, it still references the original template file for some reason, I put the above code in the functions.php file at the end after confirming compatibility with woocommerce. I am also pretty sure that the template override of the form-login.php works fine since I tried making some changes in the my-account page and it worked just fine. Hopefully I could get some help, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by redoing the woocommerce_before_customer_login_form function then writing down the code from scrath, then running it again. Hope this helps others !